# How to generate a range of Alpha numeric numbers between two numbers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a list of number from AP80000-AP81000. i need Qry to get the continues number liske 
A80000
A80001
A80002
A80003 
etc.

Comment: Your requirement does not seem to be any different than generating a range of integers in SQL Server.  Have you researched your problem at all?

Comment: hai @TimBiegeleisen i have already gone through your answer for that.but if we use the separating the  character part and replace that   and concatenate at the end will take a lot of  variables for that .This is a small part of my procedure and if i added 4 or 5 variable for that the procedure will become a complex. that's why i asked this question.  i  changed qry part to a function .thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find your number range from the given string, which you'll get by using `substring` and `charindex`. Although there are various other ways to achieve this. But for example we'll give this as try.

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = 'AP80000-AP81000'
declare @start int 
declare @end int

select 
@start = SUBSTRING( @str,3, charindex('-',@str)-3) , 
@end = SUBSTRING( @str , CHARINDEX('-',@str)+3, 5)
```

After that by using `recursive cte` you'll generate numbers of this range. You'll find more info on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
;WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @start AS NUM
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@end
)
select NUM from gen
option (maxrecursion 10000)
```

At the end you'll concatenate your suffix infront of the generated number to get your desired result.

Final code block will look like this.

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = 'AP80000-AP81000'
declare @start int 
declare @end int
select 
@start = SUBSTRING( @str,3, charindex('-',@str)-3) , 
@end = SUBSTRING( @str , CHARINDEX('-',@str)+3, 5) 

;WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @start AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@end
)
select CONCAT('AP', num) from gen
option (maxrecursion 10000)
```